# Java appropriate I/O for this code for null terminated char

Tags: java, linux, file-io, io

What is the equivalent in `Java` of this code?I have put a portion of it and I am interested in the I/O part:

```
int fd = open(FILE_NAME, O_WRONLY);  
int ret = 0;  
if (fd == -1) {         
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
}  
while (1) {  
    ret = write(fd, "\0", 1);  
}
```

**Update:**
The code does not copy files.It only writes a byte (?)/char(?) (not sure what) in the file every X seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically what you want.

```
try {
  FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(FILENAME);
  while( true ){
     os.write(0);
     Thread.sleep(2000);  // wait 2 seconds before the next write
  }
}
catch( FileNotFoundException e ){
  System.err.println("watchdog error: " + e.getMessage())
  System.exit(1);
}
```

If you really want to ignore all "write" errors as your C code does, then change the os.write to:

```
try {
  os.write(0);
}
catch( Exception we ){
  //ignoring write exception 
}
```

Comment: So `"\0"` is replaced with an integer `0`?

Comment: You can use `\u0000` for the null character

Comment: It is a character device.Does this change something?

Comment: Actually "\0" is a String object. It should be '\0' (as a char), or 0 (as an int). Note that char is widened to int without requiring an explicit cast. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2

Comment: @Javier:The device is character device.So `0` and `\0` are the same?

Comment: There is a single method write(int). But you can pass a char where an int is required. The type of the device doesn't matter, it is only how type conversions are defined in Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //open the file (throws exception if failed)
    FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream("fName"); 

    while (true) {
         //write "\0" in the file (throws exception if failed)
         fstream.write(0); 
         //sleep for 1000ms, throw exception if interrupted
         Thread.sleep(1000);
     }
 }
```

Comment: It is a character device.Does this change something?

Comment: No. It was a redundant cast.

Answer (score 0):

```
Filereader file = new Filereader("filename");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader();
String line = "";

FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("fName");
BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

    fbw.write(line + "\n");

}
```

You mean something like this? Read from one file  and write to another file.